# Have Antlr lexer handle syntax errors as tokens

Tags: java, antlr4, lexer

I'm using Antlr 4.2.2 and Java 1.7 for some text processing. I've extended BaseErrorListener and overridden syntaxError() to report syntax errors, which works well. But I want it to treat the mismatched text as a token and return it, rather than dropping it entirely.

In my lexer I have this rule:

```
TEXT : ~[<{|]+ ;
```

When I try to parse "foo { {" I get a syntax error as expected: token recognition error at: '{ {'. But I'd like that '{ {' to be reported as a token as well, so that it doesn't get dropped from the input stream.

Comment: Eh? And then what? Parse it? How?

Comment: Can you create a more complete [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a sample `.g` file and test harness? But don't just copy-paste all your code because that would clearly be too much.

Comment: EJP: There are some heuristics to process and possibly correct the syntax errors that aren't easily expressible in a grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a catchall lexer rule like this *at the end* of the file:

```
Error : . ;
```

This will produce `Error` tokens which will most likely be reported as `extra "Error" token` during parsing.

You could also do this:

```
 SilentError : . -> channel(LexingErrorChannel); // you need to set the constant for this channel
```

Which will silently ignore the lexing errors (if you like to handle/report them yourself).

But *I* would not really do this if it can be circumvented.

Note: This will produce one `Error` token per character. If you "know" possible errors, you can add other rules like this:

```
Error : [<{|]'+
      | .
      ;
```

Be careful not to be too greedy though.